# C++ calling convention for passing big objects on Linux/x86-84

Tags: c++, linux, assembly, x86-64, calling-convention

I'm trying to understand the overhead of pass object by value as a function parameter in C++/Linux/x86-64 platform.

The experimental code I used for the exploration is posted below and on godbolt.org: https://godbolt.org/z/r9Yfv4

Assume the function is unary. What I observed is:

1. If the parameter object is a 8 bytes in size, it will be put in RDI.
2. If the parameter is 16 bytes in size (contain two sub-object each 8 bytes), the two sub-objects will be put in to RDI and RSI.
3. If the parameter is bigger than 16 bytes, it will be passed via stack.

I only consider integral types and pointers and the composition types of these basic types. I know passing floats/doubles is different.

The size of `std::function` is 32 bytes (GCC/Linux implementation, long +  long + pointer + pointer = 32 bytes.). So passing `std::function` by value should look like pass `struct Person4` defined in my code. But the output assembly shows that pass `std::function` is very different from pass `struct Person3`. It looks like std::function is passed via a pointer, am I right? Why there is such a difference?

```
#include <functional>

struct Person0 {
  long name;
};

long GetName(Person0 p) {
  return p.name;
}

struct Person1 {
  long name;
  long age;
};

long GetName(Person1 p) {
  return p.name;
}

struct Person2 {
  long name;
  long age;
  long height;
};

long GetName(Person2 p) {
  return p.name;
}

struct Person3 {
  long name;
  long age;
  long height;
  long weight;
};

long GetName(Person3 p) {
  return p.name + sizeof(p);
}

long Invoke(std::function<long(long)> f) {
  return f(20) + sizeof(f);
}


int main() {
  Person3 p;
  p.name = 13;
  p.age = 23;
  p.height = 33;
  p.weight = 43;
  long n = GetName(p);

  std::function<long(long)> ff;
  Invoke(ff);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your description refers to a `struct Person4` but there is none in your code.

Comment: Could it be `std::function`'s type erasure that makes the compiler do that? (just adding to the confusion perhaps - intersting question)

Comment: @Peter  struct Person4 should be struct Person3,  thanks for pointing out this.

Answer (score 4):

The document that you want to read is the [System V ABI for x86-64](https://www.uclibc.org/docs/psABI-x86_64.pdf), in particular, section 3.2.3
«Paramater Passing»

Structs that are > 32 bytes, go always on the stack.
For structs that are <= 32 bytes, there is some logic going on:

[image: Paramater Passing Rules]

The post merger cleanup says that given that the size is greater than 2 eighbytes (16 bytes), and the first parameter is not an SSE, or any other parameter is not SSEUP, the whole aggregate is classified as MEMORY (stack).

Regarding the use of `std::function`, there is one last rule that might explain it:

> 2. If a C++ object has either a non-trivial copy constructor or a non-trivial destructor, it is passed by invisible reference (the
>    object is replaced in the parameter list by a pointer that has class
>    INTEGER)

Comment: The TL:DR: on that SSE/SSEUP stuff is that a struct or other object composed of *all* `float` / `double` members (such as `__m128`) can go in an XMM or YMM reg if its size is right; otherwise it's like any object.

Comment: Yep, that last one does it.  And indeed if you add a copy constructor or a destructor to `Person3` it then behaves the same as `std::function`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation.